# Android application ,where server responds to multiple user requests over internet

Tags: android

I am planning to develop an Android application through which multiple users with multiple roles can use it parallel(I mean synchronization over internet.)
1)It will have 2 roles, Employee and admin
2)Admin can also be employee.
3)Employee can send requests(say leaves,time sheet)
4)Admin has access to approval system.
So, I would like to have your ideas, and suggestions for its design and implementation,mainly "synchronization over internet" part.
sample app/code snippet would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Flagged to close this question, YOU should show what has been done so far to solve your problem or approach.

Comment: I really need to know, how server, client architecture works over internet (say http requests,response) works in android.